# Загрузка и скачивание файлов gRPC и Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, filestream, blazor-client-side

Миссия скинуть каким либо способом файлы 1-150мб (в среднем) на сервер.

После чего смочь его оттуда скачать.

После гугла стало понятно, что надо делать через api, на бэке gRPC с этим проблем вроде нет.

Собственно код который загружает файл:

```
    private async void UploadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())
        {
            using (var ms = file.OpenReadStream(file.Size))
            {
                var result  = new StreamContent(ms, Convert.ToInt32(file.Size));
                var bytes  = await result.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                using var serverStream = GreeterClient.DownloadFileAsync(new FileRequest  { FileName = file.Name, FileBytes = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(bytes)});
                var stream = await serverStream.ResponseAsync;
                var resultStatus = stream.Status;
            }
        }
    }
```

Но проблема в том, что файл 130мб, при выполнении

```
await result.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
```

Сжирает ~1.4 гига оперативы, что не выглядит нормальным.

Как это исправить? Возможно это сам по себе ужасный способ, но другого я не придумал.
И вопрос про скачивание, это возможно сделать без JS?

Дополню файлом proto

```
service Greeter {
  rpc DownloadFile(FileRequest) returns (StatusRequest);
}

message FileRequest {
    string FileName = 1;
    bytes FileBytes =2;
}

message StatusRequest {
string Status = 1;
}
```

Если делать так

```
int max = 1024 * 1024; 
                using (var bufferedFileStream =
                new BufferedStream(item.OpenReadStream(item.Size), max)) 
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    while ((await bufferedFileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {

                    };
                }
```

то съедает оперативы примерно столько же, сколько весит файл.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130909/discussion-on-question-by-------grpc--b).

Comment: Видимо это проблема в целом сайтов. dropmefiles тоже жрет оперативку , а если отменить загрузку файла на сервер,  то не освобождает ресурсы.